# An Image that i don't want to be affected by css is being affected by it

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm really desesperate, so please help me with this.

I'm making a website for my school project and for the images on it I wanted to make a zoom, and i found the following code to put on the `head`.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/1.3.4/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" />
    <style type="text/css">
        a.fancybox img {
            border: none; 
        } 
    </style>
```

And then the code to put in the body:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/1.3.4/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function($){
                var addToAll = true;
                var gallery = false;
                var titlePosition = 'inside';
                $(addToAll ? 'img' : 'img.fancybox').each(function(){
                    var $this = $(this);
                    var title = $this.attr('title');
                    var src = $this.attr('data-big') || $this.attr('src');
                    var a = $('<a href="#" class="fancybox"></a>').attr('href', src).attr('title', title);
                    $this.wrap(a);
                });
                if (gallery)
                    $('a.fancybox').attr('rel', 'fancyboxgallery');
                $('a.fancybox').fancybox({
                    titlePosition: titlePosition
                });
            });
            $.noConflict();
        </script>
```

What thid did, was when I clicked on every image it would zoom, but the problem is that my logo on the page also is an image, and when i put this code there, the logo goes down and I can't click it to go to the home page as it also zooms when i click.

Is there any like css cancel or something like that?

If not, then please help me.

Thanks in Advance,

And cheers.

Comment: OMG, Thank you so much man, It really helped!!! :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
$(addToAll ? 'img' : 'img.fancybox').each(function(){
```

Because `addToAll` is true, it adds the fancybox ("the zoom") to *all* images.

What you can do instead is change

```
var addToAll = true
```

into

```
var addToAll = false
```

and then in your HTML you need to change the images you want to be zoomable, so that they have a `class="fancybox`, like this:

```
<img src="logo.png">
<img src="zoomthis.jpg" class="fancybox">
```

The first image will not open in a Fancybox, the second will.